# Microsoft Cognitive Services: is it possible to use video processing api on streaming url?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I see that microsoft cognitive service video api provides video processing on downloaded video.I need to test video motion detection on a streaming url, so is it possible to do that on streaming video ? if so how can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible today. The team is thinking about it. The best way to help them to prioritize would be to open a thread in the Uservoice at https://cognitive.uservoice.com/